# Updating public arrays or lists- Java

Tags: java

So I've got some code related to a deck of cards. I've declared an Array and List outside of the methods so that they can be used by every method. But I can't figure out how to then overwrite them from within the methods. I hope that makes sense.
One method for example is used to randomly shuffle the deck of cards, but I can't figure out how to then use that shuffled deck in other methods.

```
public class deckshuffle {

    public static List<String> Deck = Arrays.asList("C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "CA", "CK", "CQ", "CJ", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8", "H9", "H10", "HA", "HK", "HQ", "HJ", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "DA", "DK", "DQ", "DJ", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "SA", "SK", "SQ", "SJ");
    public static List<String> workingDeck = Arrays.asList("C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "CA", "CK", "CQ", "CJ", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8", "H9", "H10", "HA", "HK", "HQ", "HJ", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "DA", "DK", "DQ", "DJ", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "SA", "SK", "SQ", "SJ");
    public static String[] startingArray = new String[]{"C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "CA", "CK", "CQ", "CJ", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8", "H9", "H10", "HA", "HK", "HQ", "HJ", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "DA", "DK", "DQ", "DJ", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "SA", "SK", "SQ", "SJ"};
```

That's the code for my Arrays and Lists.

```
public static void rShuffle() {
        System.out.println("Original Deck : \n" + Deck);
        List<String> shuffledDeckL = Deck;
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledDeckL);

        System.out.println("\nShuffled Deck : \n" + shuffledDeckL);
    }
```

And this takes the original deck and randomy shuffles it. But after it has been shuffled I can't access the new deck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use OOP and create a Deck with methods? Also, you should pass a deck in as a reference to `rShuffle(List<String>)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `shuffledDeckL` as a local variable, which is not accesible from outside the scope of the function. You should instead shuffle another static `List` (I assumee you must maintain the original Deck):

```
 public class deckshuffle {

   public static List<String> Deck = Arrays.asList("C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "CA", "CK", "CQ", "CJ", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8", "H9", "H10", "HA", "HK", "HQ", "HJ", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "DA", "DK", "DQ", "DJ", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "SA", "SK", "SQ", "SJ");
   public static List<String> shuffledDeck = new ArrayList<String>(Deck);
   ...
}
```

And update it in your method:

```
public static void rShuffle() {
    System.out.println("Original Deck : \n" + Deck);
    Collections.shuffle(shuffledDeck);

    System.out.println("\nShuffled Deck : \n" + shuffledDeck);
}
```

Your other classes could access it via `deckshuffle.shuffledDeck` call, as the lists are declared as public static.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Create a deck from rank-suit pairings
2. Clone the original by stream-map-collecting the items into a new list
3. Shuffle, by passing in a reference to the deck

Since you are not using OOP, by issuing methods to a Deck object, your only other choice is to pass in the reference to a static method.

Also, please adhere to the [Java naming conventions](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-in-a-name-java-naming-conventions).

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CardDeckDemo {
    private static final List<String> SUITS = Arrays.asList("C", "D", "H", "S");
    private static final List<String> RANKS = Arrays.asList("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> deck = createDeck(SUITS, RANKS);
        rShuffle(deck);
    }

    public static List<String> createDeck(List<String> suits, List<String> ranks) {
        List<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String suit : suits) {
            for (String rank : ranks) {
                deck.add(suit + rank);
            }
        }
        return deck;
    }

    public static List<String> cloneDeck(List<String> deck) {
        return deck.stream().map(String::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void rShuffle(List<String> deck) {
        System.out.println("Original Deck : \n" + deck);
        List<String> shuffledDeckL = cloneDeck(deck);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledDeckL);

        System.out.println("\nShuffled Deck : \n" + shuffledDeckL);
    }
}
```